# Excel whole column reference in array formula too slow, not respecting UsedRange?

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

I have a worksheet with many array formulas referencing another small source data sheet with a couple of rows. Formulas are as follows:

```
{=INDEX(Source!$F:$F,MATCH(1, (Source!$A:$A=$B6)*(Source!$B:$B=H$1),0))}
```

The calculation runs very slowly. When I replace the whole column references with ranges of 1000 cells, the workbook calculation speeds up significantly.

```
{=INDEX(Source!$F$1:$F$1000,MATCH(1, (Source!$A$1:$A$1000=$B6)*(Source!$B$1:$B$1000=H$1),0))}
```

I have chcecked the UsedRange on the Source sheet and it is OK and just a few rows (using ctrl+end).
Using whole column reference is quite normal practice but it does not really work well here, since it does not respect UsedRange.

Found an article on this topic:
https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2015/12/12/excel-full-column-references-and-used-range-good-idea-or-bad-idea/

that says:

> But avoid array formula and SUMPRODUCT usage of whole column reference

But why? I cannot understand the reason why Excel is not capable to limit the calculation algorithm of array formulas to the used range? Is there any other workaround?

Comment: Not all Functions check the used-range. Maybe you should format your SOURCE as tabel (CTRL-T) or name the range.

Comment: @Chris It is formatted as a table, but I need to use only indirect references, because table is created dynamically with a C# program.

Comment: Which Excel-Version do you use?

Comment: If you are building the formula at run-time then you can use `UsedRange.Rows.Count` to build the formula dynamically.

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij I am building the data dynamically, not the formula.

Comment: @Chris Excel 2016

Comment: To bad, with 365 you could  use XLOOKUP(XLOOKUP()). I think this will be faster than INDEX(MATCH()) Array Function...

Comment: @Chris About time, it should have been there 10 years ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you are building this through VBA but if it's just formulas you are using you could try something like:

```
=INDEX(Source!$F$1:$F$1000,MATCH(1,INDEX((Source!$A$1:INDEX(Source!$A:$A,COUNTA(Source!$A:$A))=$B6)*(Source!$B$1:INDEX(Source!$B:$B,COUNTA(Source!$B:$B))=H$1),),0))
```

Looks lengthy, but it basically is a dynamic way of limiting the column references to the last used row. Btw, another great tip done by @Chris in the comments is the use of an actual table instead which should speed things up even more.

Btw, you won't have to enter this through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> nomore due to the second `INDEX`